# wrong Node Kind for expected: SequenceNode was MappingNode

Tags: kubernetes

I have this manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cert-manager
  namespace: "cert-manager"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        nodeSelector:
          app.myapp.com/environment: system
```

When I try to apply with `kubectl` I get this error:

> error: wrong Node Kind for  expected: SequenceNode was MappingNode: value: {nodeSelector:
> app.myapp.com/environment: system}

What can be?

Comment: `containers:` is an array, not a dict

Comment: but it used to work, what changed?

Comment: you evidently removed the leading `-` from `nodeSelector:` turning it from an array member into a dict; `containers:` and its `initContainers:` friend have (as their name implies) always been plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @mdaniel, a container is an array, you have to mention the field name preceding with “-” inside a container. Here in your use case, removing the leading ”-” from nodeSelector: has turned the container from an array member into a dict. So, you will need to mention “-” to the nodeSelector field.

Refer to the [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for more information on how to define containers.